# VSCode plugin for solidity syntax highlighting in Markdown?

Tags: visual-studio-code, syntax, markdown, solidity

I couldn't find any VS Code plugin that provides solidity syntax highlighting for Markdown code blocks. (I tried the Markdown All in One plugin, or mardownlint).

'''solidity  just looks gray.

A workaround so far is to use '''javascript which is similar but not perfect.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Please read about what's on-topic in the [help/on-topic]. Questions asking us to find or recommend an off-site resource, like a plugin, are explicitly _off-topic_ as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam.